# Insert an `int` value into a `std::map`, which is supposed to store `std::string`

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, int

I just had the following case:

```
std::map< int, std::string > mm;
mm[ 1 ] = 5;
std::cout << mm[1];
assert( mm.find( 1 ) != mm.end() );
```

This does **NOT** print anything and the `assert` does **NOT** fail.

It appeared to be a typo, it must be `mm[ 1 ] = '5';`. After I figured it out, I tried:

```
std::string s1( 5 );
std::string s2 = 5;
```

None if this compiles. What happens?

Comment: I'd be glad if somebody suggest a better title.

Comment: the thing with 5, is that char=0x05 isnt a printable. If you had written a bigger number, you would get a recognizable char being printed.

Comment: Why should it be `mm[1] = '5'`. Should it not be `mm[1] = "5"` since you are using a string?

Comment: @0x499602D2 - it's the same in this case. But yes, could be `"5"`, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::map::operator[]` first creates an element with type `std::map::mapped_type`, then returns a reference to it.

So, what happens here is the following:

1. `std::string` object is created and default-constructed;
2. the created object is inserted into the `std::map`
3. reference to the inserted element is returned
4. `operator=` is called on this object

In this case, `std::string::operator=` is called.

And here comes the "magic" - there's an overloaded `operator=`, taking `char` as argument. Also, the number can be implicitly converted to `char`. So, what *actually* happens is:

```
std::string s;
s = (char)5;
```

For example, this:

```
mm[ 1 ] = 65; // ASCII for 'A'
mm[ 2 ] = 98; // ASCII for 'b'
std::cout << m[ 11 ] << mm[ 2 ];
```

will print `Ab`.

Comment: something annoying and something that could be easily fixed with the `explicit` C++11 keyword ...

Comment: @user2485710 - `explicit`  is not a C++11 keyword, it's before that. And it's only for constructors. We're talking about `operator=` and implicit conversion between integral types. I don't think this is relevant. Unless there's a new meaning (extended) for `explicit`.

Comment: well yes, even the `auto` keyword it's not really new in C++11, but I was "thinking out loud", it's something that doesn't make any use of the strongly typed system that C++ has to offer and even logically doesn't make that much sense. I think that the use of `explicit` could be really useful in this case and pretty much anywhere in the code where some implicit conversion between 2 types is expected; but you are right, it's still not possible.

Comment: @user2485710 the case with `auto` is different, I think. It's not possible to use `explicit` here, because `int` or `char` or any other integral type doesn't have a constructor. You can't actually put explicit anywhere. I didn't get your point about `auto` - about it's current or previous meaning?

Comment: `auto` is a reserved keyword since long time before C++11, that's pretty much all I was trying to say, C++11 adds the type deduction mechanism that gives a new meaning to `auto` but the keyword itself it's not new.